# Java regex for validating a user id.

Tags: java, regex

My regex is a little rusty and I could use some help. I am writing a regex to use for validating a user id for a java application.

The two rules that the id has to meet:

1. Must begin with a -, _, 0-9, a-z or A-Z.
2. Not allowed to contain a %, backslash, +, /, #, ::, single quote, or double quote

The part I am having trouble with is the double colon. The id can contain a single colon but cannot contain one back to back.

This is what I have come up with but it does not seem to work.

`^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]([^%\+\\\/\#'\"]|^(?!::))+$`

Any advice would be great.

Comment: *it does not seem to work* is not a problem statement.  You need to elaborate on what exactly that means.

Comment: It can't work because `^(?!::)` only fails the start of the string if it is followed with `::`. Everywhere else, it does not match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?!::)` is a negative lookahead that only fails the match when there are two colons at the start of the string.

You may use a `(?!.*::)` negative lookahead right after matching the first char:

```
String rx = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-](?!.*::)[^%+\\\\/#'\"]+$";
```

When using with `matches()`, you may omit the `^` and `$` anchors.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE9Dzi/1)

**Details**

- `^` - string start (implicit in `matches()`)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` - a word or `-` char (thus, can be reduced to `[\w-]`)
- `(?!.*::)` - no `::` after any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `[^%+\\\\/#'\"]+` - 1 or more chars other than `%`, `+`, `\`, `/`, `#`, `'` and `"`
- `$` - end of string (implicit in `matches()`)

Comment: For potential better performance, bullets 3 and 4 could be combined using `|` between valid chars excluding `:`, and a check for single `:`, e.g. `(?:[^%+\\\\/#'\":]|:(?!:))+`. This eliminates the backtracking that would otherwise be triggered by `.*`.

Comment: @Andreas I would unroll it then like [`"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-][^%+\\\\/#'\":]*(?::(?!:)[^%+\\\\/#'\":]*)*$"`](https://regex101.com/r/uE9Dzi/2) to eliminate the redundant backtracking caused by `|`.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed!